# Powershell - print only text between quotes?

Tags: powershell

How can I have the output of the following text only show the text in the quotes (without the quotes)?

Sample text"

```
this is an "apple". it is red
this is an "orange". it is orange
this is an "blood orange". it is reddish
```

becomes:

```
apple
orange
blood orange
```

Ideally I'd like to do it in a one liner if possible. I think it's regular expression with -match but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is one way

```
$text='this is an "apple". it is red
this is an "orange". it is orange
this is an "blood orange". it is reddish'

$text.split("`n")|%{
$_.split('"')[1]
}
```

This is the winning solution

```
$text='this is an "apple". it is red
this is an "orange". it is orange
this is an "blood orange". it is reddish'

$text|%{$_.split('"')[1]}
```

Comment: I tried this but I received an error: on $text.split ("`n") |%{ (doesn't contain a method named 'split')

Comment: Apologies, it did work. But, the solution is slightly different because $text has two apostrophes (one at the beginning and one at the end). In my text example, there were no apostrophes. Is it possible without them?

Comment: @MikeJ but how do you get your text ? do you use get-content ?

Comment: in this case it was $text = appcmd list apppool

Comment: try to directly split $text : $text|%{$_.split('"')[1]}

Comment: nice. That was the solution !

$text|%{$_.split('"')[1]}

Answer (score 3):

Just another way using regex:

```
appcmd list apppool | % { [regex]::match( $_ , '(?<=")(.+)(?=")' ) } | select -expa value
```

or

```
 appcmd list apppool | % { ([regex]::match( $_ , '(?<=")(.+)(?=")' )).value }
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex, i like it. But don't you think it's a bit cleaner with the Split function? Semantics at this point as they both work but I prefer the cleaner solution.

Comment: It depends on how one knows the regex syntax... Anyway I posted my answer 'cause you mentioned regex... Spli it's a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

A concise solution based on .NET method [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches), using PSv3+ syntax:

```
$str = @'
this is an "apple". it is red
this is an "orange". it is orange
this is an "blood orange". it is reddish
'@

[regex]::Matches($str, '".*?"').Value -replace '"'
```

Regex `".*?"` matches `"..."`-enclosed tokens and `.Matches()` returns all of them; `.Value` extracts them, and `-replace '"'` strips the `"` chars.

This means that the above even works with *multiple* `"..."` tokens per line (though note that extracting tokens with *embedded escaped* `"` chars. (e.g, `\"`) won't work).

---

Use of the `-match` operator - which only looks for *a* (one) match - is an option *only if*:

- you split the input into *lines*
- and each line contains *at most 1* `"..."` token (which is true for the sample input in the question).

Here'a PSv4+ solution:

```
# Split string into lines, then use -match to find the first "..." token
($str -split "`r?`n").ForEach({ if ($_ -match '"(.*?)"') { $Matches[1] } })
```

Automatic variable `$Matches` contains the results of the previous `-match` operation (if the LHS was a *scalar*) and index `[1]` contains what the 1st (and only) capture group (`(...)`) matched.

---

It would be handy if `-match` had a variant named, say, `-matchall`, so that one could write:

```
# WISHFUL THINKING (as of PowerShell Core 6.2)
$str -matchall '".*?"' -replace '"'
```

See [this feature suggestion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) on GitHub.