# Remove beginning and end of string for every value in array

Tags: arrays, powershell, substring

I have an array of data that looks like this:

```
Resource file d:\path\relevantDtata\WebConfigResource.resx is missing value for key /configuration/addSettings/add[@key="relevantData"]
Resource file d:\path\relevantDtata\WebConfigResource.resx is missing value for key /configuration/addSettings/add[@key="relevantData"]
Resource file d:\path\relevantDtata\WebConfigResource.resx is missing value for key /configuration/addSettings/add[@key="relevantData"]
Resource file d:\path\relevantDtata\WebConfigResource.resx is missing value for key /configuration/addSettings/add[@key="relevantData"]
Resource file d:\path\relevantDtata\WebConfigResource.resx is missing value for key /configuration/addSettings/add[@key="relevantData"]
```

Almost all of this data can be deleted except for a few short parts.

`Resource file d:\path\` can go away

`\WebConfigResource.resx is missing value for key /configuration/addSettings/add[@key="` can as well. and the file `"]` can too.

Currently all this data is stored in `$validationVar` I'm guessing I am wanting to playing around with substring but I'm not entirely sure what exactly needs to happen. Possibly something like the below?

```
$validationVar | % $_.substring(15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var1 = 'Resource file d:\path\relevantDtata\WebConfigResource.resx is missing value for key /configuration/addSettings/add[@key="relevantData"]'

PS C:\Scripts\so> $var1.Substring($var1.IndexOf(""""),$var1.IndexOf("""]")-$var1.IndexOf("="""))
"relevantData"
```

So you can do something like this

```
$validationVar | % { $_.Substring($_.IndexOf(""""),$_.IndexOf("""]")-$_.IndexOf("="""))}
```

or even better if you want the "RelevantData" then from this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568218/powershell-print-only-text-between-quotes).

```
   PS C:\>  $validationVar | % {$_.Split('"')[1]}
    relevantData
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `-replace` with a regular expression:

```
$pattern = '^Resource file d:\\path\\(.*?)\\WebConfigResource\.resx is missing value for key /configuration/addSettings/add\[@key="(.*?)"\]'

$validationVar -replace $pattern, '$1$2'
```