# Extract string from text file via Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have been trying to extract certain values from multiple lines inside a .txt file with PowerShell.

```
Host
Class
INCLUDE vmware:/?filter=Displayname Equal "server01" OR Displayname Equal "server02" OR Displayname Equal "server03 test"
```

This is what I want :

```
server01
server02
server03 test
```

I have code so far :

```
$Regex = [Regex]::new("(?<=Equal)(.*)(?=OR")           
$Match = $Regex.Match($String)
```

Comment: check out [print only text between quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568218/powershell-print-only-text-between-quotes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
[regex]::matches($String, '(?<=Equal\s*")[^"]+')
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dEqual%5cs*%22%29%5b%5e%22%5d%2b&i=Host%0d%0aClass%0d%0aINCLUDE+vmware%3a%2f%3ffilter%3dDisplayname+Equal+%22server01%22+OR+Displayname+Equal+%22server02%22+OR+Displayname+Equal+%22server03+test%22).

See [more ways to extract multiple matches here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24835992/3832970). However, you main problem is the regex pattern. The `(?<=Equal\s*")[^"]+` pattern matches:

- `(?<=Equal\s*")` - a location preceded with `Equal` and 0+ whitespaces and then a `"`
- `[^"]+` - consumes 1+ chars other than double quotation mark.

Demo:

```
$String = "Host`nClass`nINCLUDE vmware:/?filter=Displayname Equal ""server01"" OR Displayname Equal ""server02"" OR Displayname Equal ""server03 test"""
[regex]::matches($String, '(?<=Equal\s*")[^"]+') | Foreach {$_.Value}
```

Output:

```
server01
server02
server03 test
```

Here is a full snippet reading the file in, getting all matches and saving to file:

```
$newfile = 'file.txt'
$file = 'newtext.txt'
$regex = '(?<=Equal\s*")[^"]+'
Get-Content $file | 
     Select-String $regex -AllMatches | 
     Select-Object -Expand Matches | 
     ForEach-Object { $_.Value } |
     Set-Content $newfile
```

Comment: FYI, if the matches may span across multiple lines, replace `Get-Content $file |` with `Get-Content $file | Out-String |`, or, if you're using PowerShell v3 or newer, `Get-Content $file -Raw |`

Comment: if there are multiple `INCLUDE vmware:/?filter`What happened ? I have opened new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646160/multiple-lines-parsing-via-regex

Comment: @Arbelac Could you please explain the issue?

Comment: @Arbelac Try ``$regex.matches( $String.Split("`r`n").where({$_.contains('"')})[0] ).groups.where{$_.name -eq 1}.value | sc "c:\temp\result.txt"`` or, change the line selecting condition to a safer one, `.where({$_ -match '"[^"]+"'})`

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your regex to use a capture group, which is indicated by the parentheses. The backslashes just escape the quotes. This allows you to just capture what you are looking for and then filter it further. The capture group here is automatically named 1 since I didn't provide a name. Capture group 0 is the entire match including quotes. I switched to the Matches method because that encompasses all matches for the string whereas Match only captures the first match.

```
$regex = [regex]'\"(.*?)\"'    
$regex.matches($string).groups.where{$_.name -eq 1}.value
```

If you want to export the results, you can do the following:

```
$regex = [regex]'\"(.*?)\"'    
$regex.matches($string).groups.where{$_.name -eq 1}.value | sc "c:\temp\export.txt"
```

Comment: +1 for a nice generalization. Quibbles: No need to `\ `-escape `"`. Syntax `.where{...}` definitely works, but to me the more verbose form `.where({...})` is preferable for conceptual reasons, so that no one is tempted to use `.where {...}` (note the space), which breaks.
As an aside: alias `sc` for `Set-Content` was, for better or worse, removed from PowerShell _Core_.

Answer (score 2):

Another option (PSv3+), combining `[regex]::Matches()` with the `-replace` operator for a concise solution:

```
$str = @'
Host
Class
INCLUDE vmware:/?filter=Displayname Equal "server01" OR Displayname Equal "server02" OR Displayname Equal "server03 test"
'@ 

[regex]::Matches($str, '".*?"').Value -replace '"'
```

Regex `".*?"` matches all `"..."`-enclosed tokens; `.Value` extracts them, and `-replace '"'` strips the `"` chars.

It may be not be obvious, but this happens to be the fastest solution among the answers here, based on my tests - see bottom.

---

As an aside: The above would be even more PowerShell-idiomatic if the `-match` operator - which only looks for *a* (one) match - had a variant named, say, `-matchall`, so that one could write:

```
# WISHFUL THINKING (as of PowerShell Core 6.2)
$str -matchall '".*?"' -replace '"'
```

See [this feature suggestion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) on GitHub.

---

#### Optional reading: performance comparison

Pragmatically speaking, all solutions here are helpful and may be fast enough, but there may be situations where performance must be optimized.

Generally, using `Select-String` (and the pipeline in general) comes with a performance penalty - while offering elegance and memory-efficient *streaming* processing.

Also, repeated invocation of script blocks (e.g., `{ $_.Value }`) tends to be slow - especially in a pipeline with `ForEach-Object` or `Where-Object`, but also - to a lesser degree - with the `.ForEach()` and `.Where()` collection methods (PSv4+).

In the realm of regexes, you pay a performance penalty for variable-length look-behind expressions (e.g. `(?<=EQUAL\s*")`) and the use of capture groups (e.g., `(.*?)`).

Here is a performance comparison using the [`Time-Command` function](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27), averaging 1000 runs:

```
Time-Command -Count 1e3 { [regex]::Matches($str, '".*?"').Value -replace '"' },
   { [regex]::matches($String, '(?<=Equal\s*")[^"]+') | Foreach {$_.Value} },
   { [regex]::Matches($str, '\"(.*?)\"').Groups.Where({$_.name -eq '1'}).Value },
   { $str | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=Equal\s*")[^"]+' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object{$_.Matches.Value} } |
     Format-Table Factor, Command
```

Sample timings from my MacBook Pro; the exact times aren't important (you can remove the `Format-Table` call to see them), but the relative performance is reflected in the `Factor` column, from fastest to slowest.

```
Factor Command
------ -------
1.00   [regex]::Matches($str, '".*?"').Value -replace '"' # this answer
2.85   [regex]::Matches($str, '\"(.*?)\"').Groups.Where({$_.name -eq '1'}).Value # AdminOfThings'
6.07   [regex]::matches($String, '(?<=Equal\s*")[^"]+') | Foreach {$_.Value} # Wiktor's
8.35   $str | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=Equal\s*")[^"]+' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object{$_.Matches.Value} # LotPings'
```

Answer (score 1):

An alterative reading the file directly with `Select-String` using Wiktor's good RegEx:

```
Select-String -Path .\file.txt -Pattern '(?<=Equal\s*")[^"]+' -AllMatches|
    ForEach-Object{$_.Matches.Value} | Set-Content NewFile.txt
```

Sample output:

```
> Get-Content .\NewFile.txt
server01
server02
server03 test
```